# .htaccess PDF Catch - Tweak

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I currently use this htaccess command to catch from people hotlinking to our pdf's.  However, I would like search engines to still have access.  Really I only care that google still has access.  Can someone guide me into correctly building that into this query?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?mydomain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pdf?pdf=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Isn't it a violation of Google Search's terms of service to serve them different content?

Comment: no this isn't serving them different content.  Hotlinking protection is perfectly acceptable.  The only problem is my hotlink script written for the pdf blocks search bots.  If you are user on the site, you are serverd the content.  If another site directly links to the pdf then it takes them to a splash page, with a option to view the pdf.

Comment: figured it out.  answer posted.

Comment: also curious - why the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF Hotlink Protection, that doesn't block search engines from scanning the content.  This will keep other websites from linking directly to your PDF sheets.  You can have them forward to a splash page (so the customer knows who you are, and then click a button that says "View Pdf".  It's sent via a $_GET['pdf'] var.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Googlebot.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*bingbot.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*msnbot.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*Slurp.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?mydomain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pdf?pdf=$1 [L]
```